# XNA: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, xna

I'm currently working on a xna project, a 2D game. My problem is that when I want the bullet(poop) to appear after I pressed the Up key, i receive the error in the line which is giving the initial position to the Vector2 of my bullet(poop).

```
// for each bullet in the list, update it
foreach (Poop p in poopList)
{
   p.Update(gameTime);
}
```

In the Poop class, in the update method, i have a case, depending on the direction in which the bullet should go:
Top (1)
Right (2)
Down (3)
Left (4)

```
case 1:
                position = new Vector2(monitoPosition.X + monitoTexture.Width / 2 -     poopTexture.Width / 2, monitoPosition.Y + monitoTexture.Height / 2);

                position.Y = position.Y - speed;

                    if (position.Y <= 0 || position.Y >=500)
                        isVisible = false;
                    if (position.X <= 0 || position.X >= 800)
                        isVisible = false;

                break;
```

So in the line, in which I assign a new position to the bullet(poop), it throws the error.

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable in your code is `null`, meaning you will get an `Object reference not set an instance of an Object` error, because it is basically *nothing*. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) StackOverflow question for more info.

Double check that all your variables are assigned to.

Assuming you are talking about this line:

```
position = new Vector2(monitoPosition.X + monitoTexture.Width / 2 -     poopTexture.Width / 2, monitoPosition.Y + monitoTexture.Height / 2);
```

Make sure that `monitoPosition` and `poopTexture` are set. You can set a breakpoint on this line to pause the code, and hover over the variables to see if they are `null`.

Comment: I have now checked, and i find out that the poopTexture is the one that is null. How am I supposed to assign a texture to it; according to me, i already initialized it
     public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
        {
            monitoTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Monito");

            foreach (Poop p in poopList)
            {
                p.LoadContent(Content);
            }
        }

Comment: Whats in your `p.LoadContent(` method?

Comment: public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
        {
            poopTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Poop");
        }

Comment: Actually, you should only load your textures ONCE, it is more efficient, and most importantly, with your current method, you need to load the content again every time you add a new `Poop` to `poopList`, because it's texture has not been assigned yet.

Comment: To expand on that, make `poopTexture` a static variable, and when you call your game's `LoadContent`, do this `Poop.poopTexture = poopTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Poop");`

Comment: Your welcome! Since your new to StackOverflow I might point out, that you can click the check mark next to any answer if it solves your question, it's a way to let others know you have found a solution and gives some reputation points to the answerer.